# Trash in buffer when echoing a message from PC on Linux through a STM Nucleo board

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am working with STM NUCLEO board, managed to establish a connection between pc on Linux and a board on a serial port.
From PC I send the following message:

```
write( hSerial, "check\n\r", 7 );
```

Starting the thread, that listens on the port and writes all the messages into terminal:

```
void* thread2(void *v) 
{
   char chArrBuf [256];
   char chArrBuf2 [256];
   int n;
   memset (&chArrBuf , '\0', sizeof(chArrBuf) );
   while (1) {    
      n = read( hSerial, &chArrBuf , 1 ); 

      if (n>0) printf("%s", chArrBuf);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

For the board I'm using System Workbench and HAL library:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit( &hUART2, "EVENT:JOY_DOWN\r\n", 16 , 0xFFFF);
```

(for instance such a message, when the joystick is moved down)
The message is received and correctly displayed in terminal

But when I'm trying to read a message from PC into a buffer on the board I can see lots of trashy symbols in the terminal on PC. The code is the following:

```
i = 0;
oRecvStatus = HAL_UART_Receive( &hUART2, chArr, 50, 100 );
if( oRecvStatus == HAL_OK )
{
    while((chArr[i]!="\n")&&(chArr[i-1]!="\r")){
        Buffer[i] = chArr[i];
        i++;
    }
    Buffer[i+1] = "\n";
} 
HAL_UART_Transmit( &hUART2, Buffer, strlen(Buffer) , 0xFFFF);
```

In terminal on PC it displays " ^^J^JJ^^^Jcheck ", after several iterations and displays on terminal the message from the board, the message is being changed in something like :
"^ck^JJ^^^JJJeck
J^^"

Since I'm lacking embedded experience I can't understand what is the trick here and how I may receive a clean message from PC on the board to parse it and process correctly.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Fix your compiler warnings first.  `while((chArr[i]!="\n")&&(chArr[i-1]!="\r"))` is wrong.  Firstly, `chArr[i]` is a char, and you are comparing to a constant string.  Secondly `i-1` is out of bounds when `i=0`

Comment: I've never seen \n\r as a line ending, only \n or \r\n.